# Python Inheritance error (with private variables)

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm a beginner at coding and tried looking up the error but could not find why it showed up. Could someone please explain it to me?

My code as follows is:

```
class Automobile: 
    __material = None
    __height = None
    __width = None
    __engine_size = None  

    def set_values(self, mat, height, width, engsz="M"): 
        self.__material = mat
        self.__height = height
        self.__width = width
        self.__engine_size = engsz 
    
    def getMat(self):
        return self.__material
    def getHeight(self):
        return self.__height
    def getWidth(self): 
        return self.__width
    def getEngineSize(self): 
        return self.__engine_size

class Car(Automobile): 
    __pricePU = None

    def __findPricePerUnit(self):
        return priceDict[self.getMat] 
    def price(self): 
        return self.getWidth * self.getHeight * self.__findPricePerUnit

print("A new car is being made")
print("What are the dimensions wanted for the new car in")
mat = input("Enter material: ") 
height = input("Enter height: ")
width = input("Enter width: ")
car1 = Car() 
car1.set_values(mat, height, width)
print("A new car has been made!")
print("The price of this new car is: ")
print(car1.price)
```

---

My input for this is:

```sh
iron=10,steel=20,gold=50,diamond=100
gold
1.5
5
```

The OUTPUT shown at the end is:

```py
A new car has been made!
The price of this new car is:
<bound method Car.price of <__main__.Car object at 0x0000025DE7E84C70>>
```

I am not exactly sure why this is coming up, could someone please explain this to me!

Comment: `price` is not an attribute, it is a method (function). You therefore have to call it, i.e. `price()`. In your case, it might be better to work with (cacheable) properties. If you search for "Python properties", you'll find more. PS: Python does not really have private attributes like other, stricter languages.

Comment: You should also try to avoid mixing naming conventions; python usually uses snake casing, so `get_height`, `get_width`, etc. (or just `width()` or `height()` - or since they're just properties, `.width` and `.height` would be preferable. Using getters and setters isn't as common i Python as in Java and similar languages, since you can wrap it later in a getter/setter pair if necessary. The properties defined in your class is _class_ properties as well, and will not be default values for the attributes given in `self.<foo>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors in the code, some of which are as follows:

1. On the last line, you should execute the price function like this `car1.price()`
2. In the price function, you should execute the functions instead of multiplying the pointers of the functions, like this:

> ```
> def price(self): 
>     return self.getWidth() * self.getHeight() * self.__findPricePerUnit()
> ```

3. There is no `priceDict`, so there will be an error in `__findPricePerUnit` as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
print("A new car has been made!")
print("The price of this new car is: ")
print(car1.price())
```

Because price() is a method.